# How to compute custom metrics using Elasticsearch + Kibana?

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, sentiment-analysis

It seems like a pretty easy question, but for some reason I still can't understand how to solve the same. I have an elastic search cluster which is using twitter river to download tweets. I would like to implement a sentiment analysis module which takes each tweet and computes a score (+ve/-ve) etc. I would like the score to be computed for each of the existing tweets as well as for new tweets and then visualize using Kibana.

However, I am not sure where should I place the call to this sentiment analysis module in the elastic search pipeline.

I have considered the option of modifying twitter river plugin but that will not work retrospectively.

Essentially, I need to answer two questions :-
1) how to call python/java code while indexing a document so that I can modify the json accordingly.
2) how to use the same code to modify all the existing documents in ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want an external application to do the analysis before indexing the documents in Elasticsearch, the best way I guess is to write a plugin that does it. You can write a plugin that implements a custom analyzer that does the sentiment analysis. Then in the mapping define the fields you want to run your analyzer on.

See examples of analysis plugins - 
https://github.com/barminator/elasticsearch-analysis-annotation
https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/

To run the analysis on all existing documents you will need to reindex them after defining the correct mapping.

Comment: Yes, I decided to do the same !! Thanks, I feel more confident about it now.

Comment: If you do write one I think it will be nice if you open source it. I was surprised to see there is no such a plugin already out there, I was expecting it to be quite popular.

Comment: I second that the open source part.

Comment: @AmitGupta have you written the plugin?

Comment: I had written it a long time ago. I will see if I can find the code.